# Pull Excel data into Word with VB

Tags: excel, object, ms-word, vlookup

I need to find specific data in Excel and copy relevant information into word fields.

1) The key is stored in one of the Word fields (say "primaryID").

2) There's a primaryID column in Excel

I am using Excel Object Library reference in Word. Is there a way to "VLOOKUP" the data in Excel and copy it to Word?
Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Which programming language you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the find method of the range object? It "returns a Range object that represents the first cell where [the] information is found" according to MS VBA help.

To get the row number using VBA, assuming ids are unique:

```
workbook.WorkSheets(sheetName).Columns(primaryID_Column).Find(ID_to_find).Row
```